# Urdu fonts not rendering properly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Chrome in Ubuntu is not rendering Urdu fonts properly. It is showing gibberish characters I'm not able to read. The problem is especially bad on Facebook.

I copied some Urdu fonts under `~/.fonts` and under `/usr/share/fonts/` and updated the cache and then restarted Chrome but even that didn't work.

This is how it is appearing on my system

[image: text]

I have installed MSCore fonts and many other fonts but it's still not working.

Answer (score 27):

Download and install `nafees-urdu` fonts.

Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the `fonts-nafees` package:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-nafees
```

Then go to `chrome://settings/fonts` and select `nafees` font there in standard font and refresh your page.

or try this: http://www.urdujahan.com/linux.html

Comment: You mean restart your browser?

Comment: No need just refresh the page, that should work

Comment: Didn't work. I had to restart my browser. Using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Negative. Didnt work in 20.04. https://imgur.com/a/drvdTV4

Comment: go to chrome://settings/fonts and select nafees font there

Comment: That actually worked well, just installed and restarted the browser. Working on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Thumbs up

Answer (score 11):

I installed `fonts-noto`

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install fonts-noto
```

Restarted Chrome, and then changed the `Standard Font` in Chrome to `Noto Naskh Arabic UI`. Urdu fonts appear much better and clear now.
You can find the 'Font Settings' at: `chrome://settings/fonts`
[image: Font Preview]
[image: Chrome Settings Preview]

Update (for Firefox): You can change the fonts settings to `Noto Sans Arabic UI` in Firefox preferences Under `Langugage and Appearance section`

You can use this Chrome extension as well:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nastaleeq/oddbjmjgpaofommagnbfednbdifaakfb?hl=en

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: This solution is Chrome specific. Can you suggest something for Firefox? Yes, on Chrome, it solved the problem.

Comment: @TahirAkram Have you tried changing the `Preferences` -> `Language and Appearance` -> `Fonts and Colors` -> `Default Color` to `Noto Sans Arabic UI`?

Comment: Any ideas how to apply this solution to the WhatsApp desktop client on Linux Mint? It's an Electron app.

Comment: Haven't tried that. Did you look into changing system font to `Noto Sans Arabic UI` by using any font-tweak tool?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was was to go to

> Menu → language settings

and install "full support for urdu language".

Then, in the Firefox browser, go to

> Preferences → General → Language → Choose your preferred language for displaying pages

and change **Latin to nafees**.

Comment: This changed the default language of the browser but it will not change the font style.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that Ubuntu does not have unicode Arial fonts. 
I just found a solution that is working well on Facebook .

First you need to install 'nafees fonts' for Ubuntu.

1. Get the Chrome extension "change font family style" from Chrome store.
2. Go to its settings, in **tools > extensions**
3. Go to the extension's option.
4. Paste this **'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,nafees,sans-serif**
5. Click save, then close the window, and refresh the facebook page. it should work.

Comment: 4. Where should I paste it I didn't understand?

Answer (score 1):

Install **tahoma** fonts or install from your windows fonts directory **/windows/Fonts**

Install following chrome extension.

[Font Changer With Google Fonts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-changer-with-google/jgjhhoglgjdklldfgoffdiaceffijeke)

Go to twitter or facebook or any other site and left click the extension. Use custom settings and select tahoma. Click ok and then refresh the page.

Comment: Some other fonts also works like segoe UI, you can add them in extension custom fonts settings. you can also add urdu fonts like jameel noori nastaleeq in custom fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Guys I also had this issue and fixed with chrome extension [Nastaleeq](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nastaleeq/oddbjmjgpaofommagnbfednbdifaakfb).

Kubuntu 19.04 x64
Chrome Version: 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to `chrome settings` and search for `customize fonts` and change `standard font` to `Nafees`.
No need to install anything.

Comment: Younus, it didn't work in Chrome. This is the screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/2KgSWTf I selected Nafees as standard font. Can you suggest the same for Firefox?

Comment: Not any experience with firefox about that.

Answer (score 0):

Another Chrome extension that gave me better results is: [Wudooh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wudooh/nigfaloeeeakmmgndbdcijjegolpjfhn?hl=en). After installation, you can select Noto Nastaliq Urdu from the drop-down menu. You also have the options for adjusting the font size as well as line height.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many methods but not working
I have solved the problem via install in chrome web store this extension name is "nastaleeq"
after installing nastaleeq restart your chrome browser
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox Solution:**

I also tried to fix by adding other fonts like

1. Noto Sans Arabic UI
2. Noto Nastaliq Urdu
3. Noto Sans Urdu
4. Nafees

but that does not work.

For Firefox use this extension:
**[Urdu for Web by Fahad Yousaf](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/urdu-for-web/)**

This works for me just add to Firefox.