# Urdu Language support

Tags: 16.04, language-support

I am using Lubuntu 16.04 and notice that there is no Language support for Urdu - A language spoken by more than 300 million people in the world. As a result, Urdu fonts are not displayed correctly. Is there any walk around to handle this problem?

Comment: Maybe this question and answers to it are helpful for you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/299424/urdu-fonts-not-rendering-properly-in-chrome