# Urdu fonts in Firefox

Tags: fonts

I am using Lubuntu and having difficulty reading material in Urdu when using the Firefox browser. Is any update to the Urdu fonts available?

Comment: This may provide some suggestions, but I have no experience plus it's old so may be of limited use - https://askubuntu.com/questions/299424/urdu-fonts-not-rendering-properly-in-chrome   For maximum help you should tell us which Lubuntu you have installed (ie. 18.04 or LXDE, or 18.10 & later LXQt)

Comment: Which Urdu font are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are fonts available for Urdu in Ubuntu. You need to install fonts-nafees package from synaptic or from terminal. After that go into firefox and change fonts to nafees

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and nothing seemed to work so I went and installed the huruf extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/huruf_letters/ and it worked like a charm. I set the font to mirza and atleast in the main window everything works - though the title and other things still dont show properly.