# Urdu font is broken firefox ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox, fonts, mozilla

Urdu words are broken on `Firefox` (`version 80`) and `ubuntu 20.04` on Facebook and main search window (They are alright in wikipedia). Below is the image of broken text from search tab.
[image]

They are alright in Windows. I've installed and used Nafees font package as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/542683/864585). It corrected the shape of characters but words are still broken. Similar [thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=222388) on `linuxmint` forum provided an answer. It uses same fonts as that of chromium but there's an extra option of `"Text encoding for legacy content"` and uses Arabic in that. I can't find this option in my version of mozilla (I'm attaching picture of option available in my mozilla?

[image]

Can someone please suggest a solution or can help me to find the option `"Text encoding for legacy content"`.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `fonts-nafees` package, which provides the *Nafees Nastaleeq* font, works best under an Urdu locale. So you may want to run these commands:

```
sudo locale-gen ur_PK
sudo update-locale LC_CTYPE=ur_PK.UTF-8
```

and relogin. Hopefully that improves things.

*Edit:*

The second command adds an entry to the `/etc/default/locale` file. To undo that, open `/etc/default/locale` for editing and remove this line:

```
LC_CTYPE=ur_PK.UTF-8
```

(and relogin).

Comment: It improved Urdu characters/fonts shape (which are very nice) but words are still broken (I have attached screenshot of broken words). It has also messed the English font on Colab notebook and other websites which don't have their own font and rely on browser fonts. Can you tell me how to revert back?

Comment: @user_3pij: See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

New attempt:

- Install the `fonts-noto-core` package

  ```
   sudo apt install fonts-noto-core
  ```
- Create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-nastaliq.conf` and give it this contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Noto Serif</family>
            <family>Noto Nastaliq Urdu</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Noto Sans</family>
            <family>Noto Nastaliq Urdu</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: I installed the fonts package and created the file but I'm still facing the same issue. Urdu words are broken and english font is messed up on google Colab.

Comment: @user_3pij: Maybe a Firefox bug then.